# Google Sheets API - Use Service Account

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Please note, I'm a beginner and I'm trying my hardest to learn.

I have a functioning Discord Bot using Node JS but every 7 days I have to refresh a token for the Google Sheets API. I've read documentation online that a Service Account resolves this issue, and I've tried reading posts from here and other places to change my code to work with a service account but nothing I've tried has worked so far.

My current code I have (if you believe I'm missing something let me know) is:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {sheet} = require("../config.json")
const app = require('../app.js')

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];

const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

let gclient = undefined
exports.initialize = authorize

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFileSync(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFileSync(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        gclient = client
        return
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    console.log("Authenticated and authorized successfully!")
    gclient = client
}
```

I've looked through documentation and tried adjusting my code but I've had no luck getting through this on my own. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `Appreciate the response, I tried implementing this into my code but I was unsuccessful. I'm honestly confused at this point, I did not think it'd be very difficult to do.` and `I tried your code but it didn't work for me. Maybe I setup the service account wrong?`, I couldn't understand your current issue. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your current issue, I would like to think of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go here is as you mentioned by generating a service account that does not expire

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=yourproject

and then generate a new service account which is going to allow you to download a .json file in the form of:

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-id-here",
  "private_key_id": "privatekeyid",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxx PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service-account-name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "clientid",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/your-rpojectserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

and then you can use a code like this to read some information for that:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');

async function readColumnFromSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId, range) {
  // Load client secrets from a local file
  const client = auth.fromJSON(require('./service-account-apis-google.json'));
  console.log(client, 'client')
  client.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];

  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });

  try {
    // console.log(process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID, 'spreadsheetid')
    // console.log(sheets.spreadsheets, 'spreadsheets')
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: range,
    });

    const rows = response.data.values;
    if (rows.length === 0) {
      console.log('No data found.');
    } else {
      // Process the rows
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        console.log(row.join(', '));
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  }
}

// Use the function
const spreadsheetId = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID'; // replace with your Spreadsheet ID
const range = 'B2:B';
readColumnFromSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId, range);
```

NOTE: remember to "SHARE" with the client email above(autogenerated) on the main Gmail account file owner(if we are talking about Spreadsheets) so give the right permission for that resource and then it should work as expected